# Returning wrapped function results in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a way to return the results of the wrapped function as a string using a decorator? See code:

```
def return_value(func):
    return func

@return_value
def string_returning_function():
    return "foo"

print string_returning_function()  #=> "Running this should print a 'foo' string"
```

It currently prints out "foo" correctly, but it's not a string. **Result should be a string**

(Or it could be a string, but I wanted to manipulate "foo" inside return_value function)

It sends an error if used with string functions:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

Here's the code:

```
def return_value(func):
    return func.upper()

@return_value
def string_returning_function():
    return "foo"

print string_returning_function()  #=> "Running this should print a 'foo' string"
```

**The problem indicates that this part of the code should remain unchanged** (just create a decorator):

```
@return_value
def string_returning_function():
    return "foo"

print string_returning_function()  #=> "Running this should print a 'FOO' string"
```

Comment: Do you want to `print(repr(string_returning_function())`?

Comment: what does it return?

Comment: `type(string_returning_function()) is str`: True. Do you want the [string representation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) instead? Or `func.__name__`?

Comment: When you say it's not a string what do you mean.. the type of the returned value will definitely be a string.

Comment: The string that is returned cannot be manipulated to use string functions, such as func.upper(). Why?

Comment: If you want the wrapper to manipulate the results of string_returning_function() you will have to write a manipulating function that calls string_returning_function() and does the manipulation. Then have your decorator return that function.

Comment: With reagards to your edit, a decorator manipulates a function, not a return value. You do not need a decorator in this case.

Comment: You are passing a function to `return value`, it is `string_returning_function` that returns a string. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Getting the wrapped function results, and manipulate it. Just what the title says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments you want something like this:

```
def uppercase_return(func):
    def upper_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result.upper()
    return upper_wrapper

@uppercase_return
def string_returning_function():
    return "foo"

print string_returning_function()
```

Where `uppercase_return` constructs a new function that operates on the result of the decorated function. Then the decorator returns this wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

The decorator takes a function as input and is supposed to return a function. Your decorator should return a function that calls `func` and then calls the `upper` method of the result. `func.upper()` is not a function that calls `func` and then calls the `upper` method of the result.

To properly build the decorated function, you would `def`ine a new function inside the decorator:

```
def upperfy(func):
    def wrapper_func(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs).upper()
    return wrapper_func

@upperfy
def func():
    return 'foo'
```

Comment: Typo on "wrapped_func" and "wrapper_func", but it works if changed, though. Thanks.

Comment: @FranzNoel: Thanks, fixed.